# Remove querystring value inside repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, repeater, request.querystring

I have the below code (parts removed for ease of reading)

```
      <asp:Repeater ID="rptMenu" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptMenu_ItemDataBound">
            <ItemTemplate>
                 <li>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="hlCountries" runat="server" class="lang__option">
                        <asp:Image ID="imgGut" runat="server" />
                        <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                    </asp:HyperLink>
                </li>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

In my Item data bound (Again some code removed for ease of reading but can show if required)

```
    protected void rptMenu_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            //var nvc = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.Url.Query);
            //nvc.Remove("c");
            //string url = Request.Url.AbsolutePath + "?" + nvc.ToString();

            hlCountries.NavigateUrl = string.Format("{0}/?c={1}", 
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, p.Id);
        }
    }
```

Page load i bind the data.

When the menu hyperlink is selected it adds a parameter to the URL load some data based on the query value passed in.

When the next item in the menu item is clicked it adds another parameter i.e.

```
Page load: getdata
Click first item getdata?c=1
Click second item getdata?c=1c=2
```

(notice how the c= is repeated) How could i avoid this from happening? I added the above commented out code but that didnt work?

Comment: try `(e.Item.FindControl("hlCountries") as HyperLink).NavigateUrl = . . .`

Comment: Where would i try that?

Comment: LOL. Instead of `hlCountries.NavigateUrl = . . .` of course. Where else? :)

Comment: You are always accessing the same instance in  `rptMenu_ItemDataBound`, but you actually want to access the hyper link inside that repeater item. `e.Item.FindControl` will give the hyperlink which is rendered because of that Item, the hyperlink which resides on the same row being data bound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `UriBuilder` when building `Uri` instead of string concatenation

```
var builder = new UriBuilder(this.Request.Url);
var nvc = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(this.Request.Url.Query);
nvc.["c"] = p.Id;
builder.Query = nvc.ToString();

hlCountries.NavigateUrl = builder.Uri.PathAndQuery;
```